# URL mentioned in the CORS but sometimes it shows Failed to fetch

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-functions

I created a image/docs gallery in React app which fetch the images/docs from Azure CosmosDB.

I deploayed it in azure web app and sometimes I get this error [**Unable to fetch**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fCKb.jpg)

The origin mentioned there is already present in azure function CORS setting [**Cors setting**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7E4Mw.jpg)

I cannot understand is why only sometimes I get this error...because if CORS is blocking the origin then it should block always but it only block sometime, for example if I open the website 10 times then 2 out of 10 times it will show unable to fetch, rest 8 times it will work fine.

Should I mention something in React code also(for example..like mode:cors....or allowed-control-origin...) something like that?

```
 const getSelectedUsers = async () => {
    
    var urlprodmain = `https://example.azurewebsites.net/api/Search?OrderID=${para1}&OrderNo=${para2}&OrderName=${para3}`;

    const response = await fetch(urlprodmain, {
      method: "get",
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer" + " " + accessToken,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cors is often rejected at the destination of the packet.

You will have to allow Cors in the react app as the browser will be the one which is throwing the error.

So you will have to enable Cors in the react app.

Refer the following [article](https://www.stackhawk.com/blog/react-cors-guide-what-it-is-and-how-to-enable-it/) by Siddhant Varma